# createQuery vs createNativeQuery, performance difference for update/delete statements

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, bulkupdate, native-sql

Is there a performance difference between:

```
entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE MyTable SET coll1 = :someValue").setParameter("someValue").executeUpdate();
```

and

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("UPDATE MyTable SET coll1 = :someValue").setParameter("someValue").executeUpdate();
```

and if yes, is it high enough to use 1 approach over the another?

I am making a performance comparison between hibernate and entity framework core. In EF core this kind of thing can only be done using native SQL (well, there are third party libs) so i want to know if i should switch out all createQuery().executeUpdate() for createNativeQuery().executeUpdate() on my hibernate project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with anything of this nature, you should test on your data and your system.

However, the `createNativeQuery()` interface is designed to let you invoke SQL directly, rather than going through the ORM mapping.  You have a simple update statement here, so the generated SQL should be remarkably close to the native SQL.

You are not relying on any underlying features of the database.  There might be a little additional overhead in the translation via the ORM -- but you have already accepted that overhead by choosing to use an ORM.

I would say to stick with the framework, unless testing shows that there is a noticeable loss of performance.